# Sharepoint 2010 add fields to list definition

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
name of the List Definition project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
  <ListTemplate
      Name="LogsList"
      Type="10004"
      BaseType="0"
      OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
      SecurityBits="11"
      Sequence="410"
      DisplayName="Logs List"
      Description="Log instances for messages"
      Image="/_layouts/images/itgen.png"/>

</Elements>
```

How can I add a field? I have tried few things but fields are not appearing after the deployment.

Comment: Plese provide more details about what you have tried. Basically, you should create schema (xml) for your ListTemplate, and describe fields there in List/MetaData/Fields section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create Field definitions, create one or more Content Types, add the field definitions to then and add these content types to your list.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio 2010 or VS2008 (with WSP Builder) ??
Its few minutes job if you use the above tools rather than using NotePad !

You need to define the columns in Schema.xml

you can check this video for reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276355.aspx